# How do you make an item with display:block have rounded corners?

Tags: css, block, display

I am making a drop-down navigation bar and I am using items with display:block. How can I make the area that display:block is modifying have rounded corners?

Comment: `display: block` doesn't have anything to do with the shape of the element. It's more a way of saying you want it to have its own line.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a `border-radius` to it:

```
#block {
  display:block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nq9aacc/)